# Samsung S7 - Developer options not showing after build number pressed 7 times

Tags: samsung, developer-options

Developer options not showing after build number pressed 7 times. It even says that the developer is turned on already, but when I search for it under "about phone" on the setting app, it doesn't show up. My purpose is to turn on OEM.

Can someone help? thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This is called [RMM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3747535) protection and is a security feature of Samsung

Comment: thank you, that is probably what is going on, although in the guide you have sent me, it doesn't talk about not showing Developer options, but rather just the OEM toggle missing from the developer options, which I'm not sure can apply to be the same. I will try to search a bit more and add to this post if I solve the problem :)

Comment: btw, this is what shows up in my Download mode: 
ODIN MODE
DOWNLOAD SPEED: FAST
PRODUCT NAME: SM-G930F
CURRENT BINARY: Samsung Official
SYSTEM STATUS: Official
FRP LOCK: ON
Secure Download: Enabled
Warranty VOID: 0 (0x0000)
RP SWREV: B:8 K:6 S:7

Comment: @user323215 see "How to know if you are locked" pt 2, the "enable orm  unlock" is missing on your phone, and your download mode screen reads "FRP lock on"

Comment: @user323215 you should take a look at "How to unlock" pt 1: basically one should flash stock rom to it and leave it untouched for 7 days, then akaik the oem unlock should show up - keep in mind though, the page doesn't apply to S7, proceed at your own disk

Comment: @user323215 anyway all of these should give you enough pointers in researching the procedures applicable to your S7, i think those steps (turning off RMM, flashing etc) should be similar to S8/S9/A8 etc

Comment: @user323215 you might have already fixed it, but there you go: https://youtu.be/e74V5ftfTgk