# Android : Can't access developer option after enable the developer mode

Tags: developer-options

I tried to open developer option but when i tap the menu it said `Turn on developer options first` so i try to enable developer mode again by taping build number but is reply `No need, developer mode has already been enable`

I tried to access it by searching option in setting but when i tap any setting it would tell me to enable developer option first.

[image]

[image]

My device is Galaxy A7 (2017)
Model number SM-A720F/DS
Android 8.0.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Samsung S7 - Developer options not showing after build number pressed 7 times](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225021/samsung-s7-developer-options-not-showing-after-build-number-pressed-7-times)

Comment: whats the purpose of the screenshot when you have censored all device info?

Comment: Reddy comment works. I go to setting app then press clear data and then redo everything then im able to access developer option now