# Android 8.0.0: can not enable developer options for USB debugging?

Tags: usb, debug

Android 8.0.0: can not enable developer options for USB debugging?

When I tap the "Developer Options", says:

```
Turn on Developer options first.
```

About Phone > Software Information >  Build number.

Tap the build number, says:

```
Developer mode has already been turned on.
```

Samsung Galaxy S7.

Comment: If you search this site for the error message you will find identical questions with answers how to bypass this problem.

Comment: Searched this site. if you could provide me the link, it would be great. thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android : Can't access developer option after enable the developer mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225856/android-cant-access-developer-option-after-enable-the-developer-mode)