# How to root "Samsung Galaxy A11" (model number: SM-A115F/DSN)?

Tags: rooting, samsung

I have **SM-A115F/DSN** (Galaxy A11) running Android-10.
Can I root it and, if so, how?
Maybe someone has already rooted the same device.
I am a beginner and I need a complete **step-by-step** method. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/master/README.MD#introduction https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4139015

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225021