# Stuck in system boot loop after TWRP installation

Tags: custom-roms, twrp, boot-loop

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 and tried installing the custom ROM LineageOS because what could go wrong?

Anyways I followed [this](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/herolte/install) guide which makes you install TWRP 3.4.0-0 under the *Installing a custom recovery using heimdall* section.

I did that and I can (successfully?) boot into TWRP. However when tapping *Reboot -> System* or trying to boot into my standard android system I am stuck in a boot loop where The Samsung logo reappears every 5 seconds or so.

Here is what I've tried:

- The command  `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/fota` from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/tmobile-lg-g3/fix-recovery-loop-twrp-computer-t2873386)
- The command `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/misc bs=256 count=1 conv=notrunc` from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgv20/comments/ac6apr/got_stuck_in_an_endless_twrp_bootloop_tried/)
- Wiping my entire phone from TWRP

None of those things made any difference.

I really just hope that I didn't brick my phone.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214902
https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225021 if i understand your question you didn't install lineageos but want to boot stock ROM? that will fail for various reasons. continue installing lineageos and format userdata partition