# Help me to Unlock Bootloader on this Chinese phone

Tags: adb, rooting, fastboot, bootloader

I am trying to unlock the bootloader for my [device](https://www.whatmobile.com.pk/Qmobile_QInfinity-C) (*it's a cheap Chinese phone*) and then root using Magisk. The first problem is that OEM Unlock option is not available in developer options, so I got no choice other than try unlocking using fastboot. Now the second problem is that fastboot doesn't show anything at all. Normally there is a `Fastboot` written at the top left corner of the device but in my case there is no output but the blank screen, and I do verify that my device is in fastboot mode because when I do `fastboot devices`, it show's the output:

```
C:\Users\Mujtaba>adb devices
List of devices attached
Y3123A0310Q0100020953   device

C:\Users\Mujtaba>adb reboot bootloader

C:\Users\Mujtaba>fastboot devices
Y3123A0310Q01000209     fastboot
```

Since fastboot is responding, I tried to unlock the bootloader using different commands but each time I get read/write failed error.

```
C:\Users\Mujtaba>fastboot oem unlock
...
FAILED (command write failed (Unknown error))
finished. total time: 5.011s

C:\Users\Mujtaba>fastboot oem unlock
...
FAILED (status read failed (Too many links))
finished. total time: 80.886s
```

Alas, I got the same results with `fastboot oem unlock-go` and `fastboot flashing unlock` as fastboot is not picking up (*at least I think*) any command except for `fastboot devices`.

I read the official [guide](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/locking_unlocking#unlocking-bootloader) and there I found that:

> Devices should deny the fastboot flashing unlock command unless the
> get_unlock_ability is set to 1. If set to 0, the user needs to boot to
> the home screen, open the Settings > System > Developer options menu
> and enable the OEM unlocking option (which sets the unlock_ability to
> 1).

My device supports unlocking bootloader because I've checked the `build.prop` file using `adb shell getprop` and it includes the properties stated below:

> The ro.oem_unlock_supported property should be set at build time based
> on whether the device supports flashing unlock.
>
> If the device suppports flashing unlock, set ro.oem_unlock_supported
> to 1. If the device doesn't support flashing unlock, set
> ro.oem_unlock_supported to 0. If the device supports flashing unlock,
> then the bootloader should indicate the lock status by setting the
> kernel command line variable androidboot.flash.locked to 1 if locked
> or 0 if unlocked.
>
> For devices that support dm-verity, use ro.boot.verifiedbootstate to
> set the value of ro.boot.flash.locked to 0; this unlocks the
> bootloader if the verified boot state is orange.

```
C:\Users\Mujtaba>adb shell getprop
[ro.oem_unlock_supported]: [1]
[ro.boot.verifiedbootstate]: [green]
[ro.boot.flash.locked]: [1]
[sys.oem_unlock_allowed]: [0]
.
.
```

Someone on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/90szus/run_fastboot_oem_unlock_without_enable_oem_unlock/e2uizr7?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) did this to find the OEM unlock state, mine of course returned 0 as you can see above.

```
adb shell getprop sys.oem_unlock_allowed
```

**Device Specs:**

CPU: ARM Cortex-A-7 @ 1.20 Ghz

GPU: Mali-400 MP

Board: sp7731cea (Unisoc aka Spreadtrum)

Build: Q Infinity C_MP_26_01

Treble: NA

Seamless update (A/B): NA

So long story short, I'm still unable to unlock the bootloader so any help would be very helpful guys. Thanks

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/flash-pac-stock-rom-android-smartphone

Comment: if OEM Unlock option is not available you need to find some app/ROM/workaround which reveals that. you may succeed with flashing (AVBv1 signed) magisk_patched.img on locked bootloader. once you have rooted you may enable OEM unlocking from cmd line. unfortunately i can't help flashing pac, don't know if it is even possible to flash single partition from SPD flash tool

Comment: for samsung devices one must insert SIM for 7 days, worth a try https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225021

Comment: @alecxs but i still need my boot.img file for magisk right??

Comment: @alecxs when patching boot.img from magisk, will it use avb1 or 2 by default?

Comment: only AVBv1 is supported, assuming your device is running Android 7