# Stuck in twrp after trying to root Samsung A7(2018)

Tags: samsung, rooting, twrp, odin, magisk

I tried to root my samsung A7 yesterday, I flashed twrp with odin and when I try to install magisk it says "Zip file is corrupt",

I don't have any OS now and I'm left with only twrp.

I flashed twrp again different times with odin but same.
I can't boot in fastboot and when I tried with adb sideload my device is not discoverable.
I followed all the steps from this video [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMP0txX-iGM) when I tried to root my device.

Is there anyway to bring my samsung back or it's bricked?

Device Model: A750FN

[image]

Comment: Flashing TWRP (or Magisk) does not remove the OS. In fact, how can you even flash Magisk if you don't have any OS? What happens when you try to reboot system?

Comment: i recommend to install RMM-State_Bypass_Mesa_v2.zip otherwise you may get permanently locked https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225021

Comment: @WrichikBasu I meant I don't have an boot image anymore, when I power it off and then try to start it, it goes in recovery mode.

Comment: @alecxs first I flashed an file called magisk_patched_boot.rar with odin then I flashed twrp, then I booted in twrp and tried to install magisk but it didn't work, I tried many times and still the error is always the same

Comment: @alecxs I tried but I can't cause when I try to install from twrp it shows the invalid zip error for every file I try, not only for magisk

Comment: format userdata partition. transfer zip files via *adb push*. disable signature verification. install zip again and *'adb pull /tmp/recovery.log'* right after error. share log via https://pastebin.com (after removing your serialno from log)

Comment: @WrichikBasu I just tried to reboot system and the phone ended up in samsung logo loop

Comment: @alecxs I tried wipe/Format Data but when I try with adb devices it doesn't show up in console, do I need to boot in download mode to try adb or from twrp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118929/discussion-between-g3n1t0-and-alecxs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@alecxs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/404820) I was able to fix it. The reason why I was stuck in twrp is because I wiped system through twrp(I was frustrated when I couldn't boot in magisk after many times of trying so I decided to let the System go,  the first time trying to root an phone so I didn't know what I was doing).

DON'T WIPE THE SYSTEM!

I still don't know why "Zip file is corrupt" ocurred, maybe because I tried to install magisk through sd card and the sd card was corrupted, or maybe because the twrp I flashed was unofficial, I don't know, but here is how you can recover your phone back:

1.Install the stock rom/firmware for your model at [samfw.com](https://samfw.com/),

before you install the stock rom for your phone model you should know your phone CSC(Country Specific Code), if you don't know it just boot in download mode and you will see Carrier ID associated with phone CSC Code

2.Boot in download mode and flash the downloaded rom. If that goes well and now you have your phone back but you still want to root then go to [Magisk Installation Guide](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html) and follow the instructions.

If you experienced the same error like mine while trying to flash magisk on twrp with sd card then next time instead of sd card try to copy magisk in cache partition and then in twrp flash from there.