# How we can know from Download Mode screen if device (Galaxy Tab S6) is factory-new?

Tags: rom-flashing, warranty, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-6

[[image]] download screen for my Tab S6[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCpqt.jpg)

Picture above is from my Tab S6's download screen. Do you see any clue showing that this device is not brand-new? For example anything that should be locked but not locked now or any warranty that has voided or anything other than normal as brand-new?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Samsung S7 - Developer options not showing after build number pressed 7 times](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225021/samsung-s7-developer-options-not-showing-after-build-number-pressed-7-times)

Comment: that post is useful but not much relevant to this topic

Comment: What does that (L) following OEM LOCK mean ?

Comment: Factory-new devices do originally come with KG STATUS : PRENORMAL? What should be the original KG STATUS for factory-new devices?

Comment: OEM lock: on (L) means locked. your bootloader is locked. Warranty void: 0 means your warranty is valid, therefore this device never was unlocked before and is still in factory state. state **pre**normal is not normal, it means you are not allowed to unlock bootloader (as explained in the linked xda thread). this is probably some recent policy change due a samsung security roll-out in Jun 2020

Comment: Thanks, this is important for me as I'm trying to find some evidence to prove that this device is not brand-new or not in factory state if it is so. This device production date is July 17, 2020 so it is probable that this KG being PRENORMAL is for the recent policy change. But we need a proof for existing that policy change. Is there any?

Comment: nobody knows anything. this is pure speculation (so far) https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-17-06-2019-rmm-kg-bypass-root-install-twrp-on-exynos-samsung-after-2018.3747535/post-84311531

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bounty-fix-for-persistent-rmm-state-lock-after-7-days.3886716

Comment: This particular device has Android 9 and I believe that has been flashed back to Android 9 by the seller because Android 10 update for this has rolled out in early April 2020 and so this device with production date of July 2020 should originally comes with Android 10. We suppose that this Prenormal condition is a factory state, now is it possible to flash back while KG is already PRENORMAL?

Comment: (I don't remember where I read that when device KG becomes PRENORMAL, no longer can flash even stock ROM) Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: bootloader has anti-rollback protection, flashing lower bootloader level is impossible. prenormal means *"only official released binaries are allowed to be flashed"*

Comment: BTW according to Chimera RMM lock and KG lock is two different locks; and in my case, KG (but not RMM) is showing in Download screen.
 https://chimeratool.com/en/docs/samsung-knox-guard-kg-and-remote-monitoring-and-management-rmm-unlock-functions