# How to unlock bootloader on Samsung Galaxy S6 Lite?

Tags: bootloader-lock

I have a new SM-P610 device that I want to install [Lineageos](https://lineageos.org/) on. I am following the instructions at
https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/gta4xlwifi/install
but I am unable to unlock the boot loader.

Under "developer options" on the phone I can toggle "OEM unlocking" and changing this
is reflected on the download mode screen which shows either "OEM LOCK: ON(L)" or "OEM LOCK: ON(U)", so
obviously Locked or Unlocked, however ON in both cases.

If I try to run the heimdall command to flash the recovery image it prints "ERROR: Failed to receive session end confirmation!" and on the screen "Custom Binary(RECOVERY) Blocked By OEM Lock" is displayed in red.

So how do I actually unlock the boot loader?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Samsung S7 - Developer options not showing after build number pressed 7 times](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225021/samsung-s7-developer-options-not-showing-after-build-number-pressed-7-times)

Comment: Not related at all.

Comment: I am just linking important information for other users who come here for *"How to unlock bootloader on Samsung Galaxy"*

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured it out. The guide says

> With the device powered off, hold Volume Down + Volume Up and connect USB cable to PC.
> Now, click the button that the onscren instructions coorelate to “Continue” and/or “Unlock Bootloader”.

and on the screen the tablet displays

```
Volume up: Continue
```

This I assumed was a perfect implementation match for the generic *“Continue” and/or “Unlock Bootloader“* description,
but clicking volume up will just end up in the situation I described in the question.

However on the next line (which I did not read since I had already found a perfect match...) it says

```
Volume up long press: Device unlock mode
```

So the device requires a **long press** to actually unlock the boot loader (which is not described in the install instructions). I did not notice this line
until now when writing the answer, I found the long click information in this [xda forum post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/help-custom-binary-boot-blocked-by-oem-lock.4115109/post-84561859).

---

After the successful unlock procedure the tablet behaved as expected (all apps/settings reset/deleted, it now nags about the boot loader being not being verifiable upon
every boot, and the OEM unlocking option in developer options is greyed out with status "Bootloader already unlocked".)

Comment: OEM unlocking option in developer options is first important step missing in your answer (I didn't read the question, like most users who come here for solution)

Comment: That was explicitly mentioned in the question.