# attempt to install twrp 3.0.0.0 on Samsung G930U (heroqlteue) fails

Tags: twrp, samsung-galaxy-s7

I downloaded TWRP from [here](https://androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=51971) and Odin from [here](https://www.chip.de/downloads/Odin3_12992520.html) and tried flashing the .img file which I compressed to .tar using 7zip.

Odin outputs that:

```
<ID:0/005> Added!!
<ID:0/005> Odin engine v(ID:3.1401)..
<ID:0/005> File analysis..
<ID:0/005> Total Binary size: 17 M
<ID:0/005> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/005> Initialzation..
<ID:0/005> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/005> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/005> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/005> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/005> recovery.img
<ID:0/005> RQT_CLOSE !!
<ID:0/005> 
<ID:0/005> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

using Odin with the downloaded .md5 file gets me this:

```
<ID:0/005> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/005> Odin engine v(ID:3.1401)..
<ID:0/005> File analysis..
<ID:0/005> Total Binary size: 17 M
<ID:0/005> SetupConnection..
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
<ID:0/005> Removed!!
<ID:0/005> Added!!
<ID:0/005> Odin engine v(ID:3.1401)..
<ID:0/005> File analysis..
<ID:0/005> Total Binary size: 17 M
<ID:0/005> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/005> Initialzation..
<ID:0/005> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/005> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/005> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/005> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/005> recovery.img
<ID:0/005> FAIL! (Auth)
<ID:0/005> 
<ID:0/005> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

And my phone beeing in download mode outputs a red colored line `SECURE CHECK FAIL : recovery` in both cases

Using exactly [this](https://androidbiits.com/root-samsung-galaxy-s7-sm-g930u-easily/) tutorial step by step Odin outputs this:

```
<ID:0/005> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> CF-Auto-Root-heroqlteue-heroqlteue-smg930u.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/005> Odin engine v(ID:3.1005)..
<ID:0/005> File analysis..
<ID:0/005> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/005> Initialzation..
<ID:0/005> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/005> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/005> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/005> recovery.img
<ID:0/005> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/005> cache.img.ext4
<ID:0/005> FAIL! (Auth)
<ID:0/005> 
<ID:0/005> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Can someone tell me how to install twrp onto this device or root it anyhow else?

Comment: unlock bootloader first

Comment: I guess I can't unlock it for this device.. I enabled unlocked oem bootloader in developer settings before doing that odin action, but it doesn't work nevertheless

Comment: The  NAM variant (U, U1) can't be unlocked in the first place. `heroqlte` applies to the CN variant (G9300).

Comment: I assume you want to tell me, that I have the CN variant wich can be unlocked (?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unlock bootloader on Samsung Galaxy S6 Lite?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242064/how-to-unlock-bootloader-on-samsung-galaxy-s6-lite)

Comment: @qGold Quite the opposite, you have the NAM variant which is a dead end.

Comment: Oh damn. So  I guess I have to look for another phone..

Comment: @alecxs that doesn't work for my phone :(

Comment: once you got SECURE CHECK FAIL you must start from scratch (including 7-days waiting period for RMM prenormal)

Comment: Okay.. see you again in 7 days with most probably another error^^