# How to root samsung galaxy s6 SM-G920F android 7

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s

I want to root my phone **Samsung S6 SM-G920F android 7**. I have tried app like *kingroot, kingoroot, z4root, towelroot*... but none of this work

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are the rooting apps not working anymore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205706/why-are-the-rooting-apps-not-working-anymore)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Samsung S7 - Developer options not showing after build number pressed 7 times](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225021/samsung-s7-developer-options-not-showing-after-build-number-pressed-7-times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for samsung devices patch whole [AP_*.tar.md5](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#instructions) ROM file with Magisk (instead `boot.img`)